# Crystal Show All In Group If XX Exists

Tags: crystal-reports

I can achieve this with a suppress but that makes the report run super slow. I want to write this into record selection. If you can help I appreciate it immensely.

data structure

```
Date | Field_A | Field_B
11/1 |   ABC   |   315
11/1 |   ABC   |   217
11/1 |   DEF   |   217
```

What I want to display is any record that has a 315 in Field_B and any other record with the same date and Field_A. So in this example it would show the first two records but not the third because even though it has the same date it has a different Field_A.

I hope this makes sense. I am happy to clarify any further if required. Again I want to get this in the record selection but I have no idea where to start with this type :/

Thank you

Comment: I assume this will use a while function but I have never had to write anything like this before. I appreciate the help on this.

Comment: You can do this easily with a query.. try to search using odbc connection of crystal report wizard